# Show that $\int |\nabla f|^2 dx = \int|\nabla \times f|^2dx$ if $\nabla \cdot f = 0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth function such that $\nabla \cdot f = 0$. For a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, I would like to prove the identity $$\int_\Omega |\nabla f|^2 dx = \int_\Omega|\nabla \times f|^2dx.$$
I think this can be proven using integration by parts but I am having some trouble doing this and I think I am missing a vector identity.

What is the needed identity here?

Comment: What do you mean by the gradient of a function $\mathbb{R}^{3}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: Do you define $|\nabla f|^2$ as $\partial_if_j\partial_if_j$? If so, I recommend [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) so you can combine IBP with $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm}=\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}$.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku The result would be a matrix/2-tensor where the $i,j$-th element would be $\partial f/\partial x_j$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes that is the definition I am using. Thank you, I will try doing it in components.

Comment: And how do you define its absolute value?

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku The sum of the absolute value of each entry, i.e. $\sum_{i,j} |\partial f_i/\partial x_j|$

Comment: So, let me make it clear, this is the _square of the sum of absolute values_, not _the sum of squares_?

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku Yes that is correct, $|\nabla f| = \sum_{i,j} |\partial f_i/\partial x_j|$

Comment: Let me be double clear, this is the $\ell^1$-norm $$|\nabla f|=\sum_{i,j}\left|\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right|$$ and not the $\ell^2$-norm (a.k.a. Frobenius norm) $$|\nabla f|=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right)^2},$$ is it correct? I am asking this because it is relatively rare to see $\ell^1$-norm being used in vector calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly believe that all the norms involved are $\ell^2$-norms. Indeed, accepting this interpretation, a pure algebraic computation shows that

\begin{align*}
\|\nabla f\|_{\ell^2}^2
&= \| \nabla \times f\|_{\ell^2}^{2}
+ (\nabla \cdot f)^2
+ \sum_{i, j} \left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_j}  \right). \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Now assuming that $f \in C_c^2(\Omega)$, meaning that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable and is supported on a compact subset of $\Omega$, then integration by parts and [Clairaut's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) show that

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}\, \mathrm{d}x
&= - \int_{\Omega} f_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left( \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= - \int_{\Omega} f_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_j} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_j}\, \mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}

hence

$$ \int_{\Omega} \left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_j} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0. $$

So by integrating both sides of $\text{(1)}$ on $\Omega$, we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} \|\nabla f\|_{\ell^2}^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{\Omega} \| \nabla \times f\|_{\ell^2}^{2} \, \mathrm{d}x
+ \int_{\Omega} (\nabla \cdot f)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Now the desired conclusion follows by invoking the assumption $\nabla \cdot f = 0$.

Comment: Seconded. An additional term that does not cancel out is present if you calculate the norm as described by the OP.

Comment: You are right, I incorrectly thought the norm was $\ell^1$ when it should have been $\ell^2$. Thank you!